# Why cin doesn't recognize enter key, as cin.get does?

Tags: c++, cin

For example, if write those statements in code:

```
char a[10];
char b[10];
cin>>a;
cin>>b;
```

`cin>>b;` doesn't see <kbd>Enter</kbd> key that was pressed after typing, for example, Hello

but when instead `cin>>b;` write `cin.get(b, 10);` then `cin.get(b, 10);` reads <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from previous statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't see Enter key that was pressed after typing?" Do you mean that it did not move the cursor to a new line in the console?

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. Did you mean for those arrays to be `char`?

Comment: @SebastianRedl It's typo, sorry

Comment: Also, don't use character arrays. C++ has a proper string type: `std::string`.

Comment: @milleniumbug Ok, I'm just learning C++ by reading C++ Primer Plus, and I haven't started reading about it yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working under the assumption that `a` and `b` are arrays of `char` here, because otherwise your question does not make sense.

`get` is an "unformatted" input function, meant to read the input as it comes into the stream. That's why it reads the newline.

`>>` is a "formatted" input function, meant to read a specific type of data in a natural way. In particular, `>>` with a `char` array reads a single word, i.e. a sequence of characters not containing whitespace. This is why it stops reading when it encounters the newline, which is whitespace.